# My iPhone app doesn't use the full screen on iPhone 5 once on App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store

so I've been searching to find an answer to this problem but no one seems to have had the same trouble as I am having.

I have created a simple iPhone game in my spare time and this is what is happening:

I have an iPhone 4s and my sister has an iPhone 5.
The game works great on both of our phones when testing from Xcode. There is no trouble with screen size or resolution. The proper splash screen/loading screens appear and than the game filled each screen properly.

Now, however, when I have released the first version of my game onto the App store, I had my sister download it with her 5 only to find that there are black bars at the top and bottom of the screen.

I am unsure as to why this is happening because the Default-568h@2x.png is loading properly (filling the screen) but than the actual app does not.

I'm not sure if it affects it at all but the game is only allowed to be viewed in portrait mode.

Comment: Try cleaning your build in xcode (cmd + shift + k), delete the app off the iPhone 5, and build it onto the device again from xcode. Does it display correctly?

Comment: Well as I said it works fine when testing on the devices from Xcode, it's the download from the Apple App Store that has the black bars, doesn't really make any sense haha

Comment: Did you try what I asked though? Cleaning and rebuilding fresh can make a difference. If you built it onto the phone once then kept building onto it, a bug with the splash screen might not have appeared.

Comment: I did and now I've uncovered a bigger bug so as soon as I sort that out I will come back to this to let you know if it worked, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Okay, hope that helps.